# Iteration of panel data group by and diff

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, diff

I want for each id , whenever `track==2` compare to all the rows of the id which have `track==1` and see if the difference in `time` is greater than or equal 0 and less than 2 hours difference. If this condition is complete tag it in some way, maybe a new column with dummy, 1 if the condition is succesfull and 0 when is not.

This an example to illustrate my problem (df is much bigger than this example)

```
                time  track  id
2018-07-06 08:34:44       1   1
2018-07-06 09:15:46       1   1
2018-07-19 08:15:50       1   1
2018-07-24 11:16:23       1   1
2018-07-06 08:34:44       2   1
2018-07-06 09:15:46       2   1
2018-07-19 08:15:50       2   1
2018-07-24 11:16:23       2   1

2018-07-06 07:34:44       1   2
2018-07-06 07:36:46       1   2
2018-07-19 18:15:50       1   2
2018-07-24 19:16:23       1   2
2018-07-06 10:34:44       2   2
2018-07-06 10:15:46       2   2
2018-07-19 21:15:50       2   2
2018-07-24 23:16:23       2   2
```

possible solution

```
                time  track  id   condition_complete
2018-07-06 08:34:44       1   1                    0
2018-07-06 09:15:46       1   1                    0
2018-07-19 08:15:50       1   1                    0
2018-07-24 11:16:23       1   1                    0
2018-07-06 08:34:44       2   1                    1
2018-07-06 09:15:46       2   1                    1
2018-07-19 12:19:50       2   1                    0   # watch that  2018-07-19 12:19:50 - 2018-07-19 08:15:50 is greater than 2 hours so condition must not be completed  
2018-07-24 11:16:23       2   1                    1

2018-07-06 07:34:44       1   2                    0
2018-07-06 07:36:46       1   2                    0
2018-07-19 18:15:50       1   2                    0
2018-07-24 19:16:23       1   2                    0
2018-07-06 10:34:44       2   2                    0
2018-07-06 10:15:46       2   2                    0
2018-07-19 21:15:50       2   2                    0
2018-07-24 20:16:23       2   2                    1
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that you have tried?

Comment: I use a left join but iam killig the memory